# Apple app store app showing app is not available in country/region even selecting all countries

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect

I have released a new app onto the Apple app store and Google Play store. Now post release when I opened the app it says not available in country or region

I have made sure that all countries are selected in App Store Connect.  I do not understand however why when all countries are selected in Apple Connect why people would still be getting this error.

Any advice or suggestions?

If any suggestions on how I can resolve that error.

Comment: This has nothing to do with ionic...

Comment: Im having the same problem, waiting for more than 5 days